# How to stop subtracting when it reach number 0

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```js
module.exports = function Cart(oldCart) {
    this.items = oldCart.items || {};
    this.totalQty = oldCart.totalQty || 0;
    this.totalPrice = oldCart.totalPrice || 0;

    this.add = function(item, id, image) {
        let storedItem = this.items[id];
        if(!storedItem) {
            storedItem = this.items[id] = { item: item, image: image, qty: 0, price: 0, id: id};
        }
        storedItem.qty++;
        storedItem.price = storedItem.item.price * storedItem.qty;
        this.totalQty++;
        this.totalPrice += storedItem.item.price;
    };

    this.reduceByOne = function(id) {
        this.items[id].qty--;
        this.items[id].price -= this.items[id].item.price;
        this.totalQty--;
        this.totalPrice -= this.items[id].item.price;
        // minimum number 0
    };

    this.addByOne = function(id) {
        this.items[id].qty++;
        this.items[id].price += this.items[id].item.price;
        this.totalQty++;
        this.totalPrice += this.items[id].item.price;
    };

    this.removeItem = function(id) {
        this.totalQty -= this.items[id].qty;
        this.totalPrice -= this.items[id].item.price;
        delete this.items[id];
    };
    
    this.generateArray = function() {
        var arr = [];
        for (var id in this.items) {
            arr.push(this.items[id]);
        }
        return arr;
    };
}
```

I was wonder what might be a maintainable way to force the reduceByOne function to have a minimum number of 0 (not -1, -2 and so on which happen now). So it should stop subtracting when it reach number 0. But keep in mind that this function should not affect other functions as well. I wrote a condition inside the `this.reduceByOne function` already and the only thing that thing should do now is to check if the this.items[id].qty have a number 0.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is too broad, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have already narrow down the question, not sure what you trying to tell me?

Comment: you need to provide a minimum code example to show only your issue you're asking for help on, not your whole project code. the issue here is is about a minimum number of 0's, not the whole application.

Comment: This is not even a whole application, please find the out commented text, I know you dont want to solve this problem probably or are lazy to read my code, but giving this code will give you a better picture of what I mean.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Word of advice - be polite, no one wants to help someone who calls them 'lazy'

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking about. What number exactly do you need to set? totalPrice?

Comment: the function this.reduceByOne will subtract -1 each time, when the number reach 0, it should stop subtracting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just check if item's qty is 0 and if it's 0, just return, don't do anything

```
this.reduceByOne = function(id) {
    if(this.items[id].qty == 0) return;
    this.items[id].qty--;
    this.items[id].price -= this.items[id].item.price;
    this.totalQty--;
    this.totalPrice -= this.items[id].item.price;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Either functions that do subtraction can take care of that:

```
this.totalPrice = Math.max(0, this.totalPrice - this.items[id].item.price);
```

instead of

```
this.totalPrice -= this.items[id].item.price;
```

Notice that `Math.max` doesn't cover possible `NaN`.

Or this can be done with accessors:

```
get total() {
  return this._total || 0;
}

set total(v) {
  if (v >= 0)
    this._total = v;
}
```

This also covers default value like `this.totalPrice = oldCart.totalPrice || 0`.